# What is the quickest way to simplify : $\left(\frac{2u^{-5}v^2}{8w}\right)^{-2}$ ( Barton 's College Placement Test).

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, exponentiation

What is the most efficient strategy to symplify : $\left(\frac{2u^-5v^2}{8w}\right)^{-2}$ at minimal coast, I mean, with the minimal amount of necessary and sufficient manipulations?

A slightly different question : how would you actually proceed during a test such as Barton's?

Let's say that every application of an algebra rule or of an arithmetic fact  counts here as a manipulation.

Source : Barton College Placement Test ( https://www.barton.edu/pdf/math/practice-math-placement-test.pdf)

I can't do better than *at least 9* manipulations :

$\left(\frac{2u^{-5}v^2}{8w}\right)^{-2}$

= $\left(\frac{1u^{-5}v^2}{4w}\right)^{-2}$  ( by  2/8 = 1/4)

= $\left(\frac{1u^{-5}v^2}{4w}\right)^{(-1)(2)}$   ( by $-2$ = $-1\times 2$)

= $\left(\frac{1u^{-5}v^2}{4w}\right)^{(2)(-1)}$   ( by : mult. commutativity )

= $\left(\frac{1^2u^{-10}v^4}{16w^2}\right)^{(-1)}$  ( by $\left(\frac ab\right)^n$= $\frac{a^n}{b^n}$ , by $(ab)^n = a^n\times{b^n}$ and by $(a^n)^m$ = $a^{nm}$, applied several times).

= $\left(\frac{16w^2}{1^2u^{-10}v^4}\right)$  ( by $\left(\frac ab\right)^{-1}$ = $\frac{b}{a}$ )

= $\left(\frac{16w^2}{1^2v^4}\frac{1}{u^{-10}}\right)$ ( by : 1 is the $\times$ identity and by $\times$ commutativity)

= $\left(\frac{16w^2u^{-(-10)}}{1^2v^4}\right)$  ( by $a^{-n}= \frac{1}{a^n}$)

= $\left(\frac{16w^2u^{10}}{1^2v^4}\right)$ ( by : $ - (-a) = a$)

= $\left(\frac{16w^2u^{10}}{v^4}\right)$ ( by $1^2 = 1$ and $1$ is the identity element for  $\times$).

Comment: I can only see nine.

Comment: I counted every application of any rule ( even when occurring at the same line)

Comment: It is very subjective in my opinion unless authorized operations are precisely listed, for instance why not using $(a^n)^{-2}=a^{-2n}$ directly, do you have a restriction on $m>0$, etc... ? An operation can be considered atomic for someone and multistep by someone else. That is why rules need to be made explicit.

Comment: I still only see nine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix all negative exponents, starting with the outer-most. $(a/b)^{-n} = (b/a)^n$

$$\left(\frac{2u^{-5}v^2}{8w}\right)^{-2} =\left(\frac{8w}{2u^{-5}v^2}\right)^{2}  $$

$$ = \left(\frac{8wu^5}{2v^2}\right)^{2}  $$

Reduce

$$\left(\frac{4wu^5}{v^2}\right)^{2}$$

Distribute exponent

$$ = \frac{(4wu^5)^2}{(v^2)^2}  $$

Square each

$$ = \frac{16w^2u^{10}}{v^4}  $$

Comment: Thanks for the method you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

$$\begin{align*}\left(\dfrac{2u^{-5}v^2}{8w}\right)^{-2} & = \left(\dfrac{u^{-5}v^2}{4w}\right)^{-2} \text{ (Cancel 2 from top and bottom)} \\ & = \left( u^{-5}v^24^{-1}w^{-1} \right)^{-2} \text{ }\left(\text{Because }\dfrac{1}{a} = a^{-1} \right)  \\ & = u^{(-5)(-2)}v^{2(-2)}4^{(-1)(-2)}w^{(-1)(-2)} \left(\text{Because }(a^bc^d)^e = a^{be}c^{de} \right) \\ & = 16u^{10}v^{-4}w^2 \left(\text{By commutativity of multiplication}\right)\end{align*}$$

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I was wondering how to do this in test conditions.